# SQL Server 2008 Rows to 1 CSV field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, csv, concatenation

We're on SQL Server 2008 and I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to have a stored procedure return my results in 1 CSV field

for example:

```
SELECT TOP 4 carModels
FROM dbo.Models
```

would return

```
Jeep
Honda
Mitsubishi
Ford
```

I would like this returned in 1 field like so:
Jeep,Honda,Mitsubishi,Ford

I know we can do this with an assembly, temp tables, or server side code but would prefer not to go that route. Are there any tips / tricks you could suggest to get the result I'm looking for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this:

```
DECLARE @x varchar(8000)

SELECT TOP 4
    @x=ISNULL(@x+', ','')+carModels
    FROM dbo.Models

SELECT @x AS carModels
```

**EDIT** same answer as above, but here is complete code to test it out...

```
declare @Models table (RowID int not null primary key identity(1,1), carModels varchar(20))
insert into @Models values ('Jeep')
insert into @Models values ('Honda')
insert into @Models values ('Mitsubishi')
insert into @Models values ('Ford')
insert into @Models values ('Mazda')

DECLARE @x varchar(8000)
SET @x=null
SELECT TOP 4
    @x=ISNULL(@x+', ','')+carModels
    FROM @Models

SELECT @x AS carModels
```

output:

```
carModels
----------------------------------
Jeep, Honda, Mitsubishi, Ford

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: how can you join the csv value to a select with other related data?

Answer (score 0):

The following might work.  I don't have SQLServer today to verify.

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(8000)
    SET @Str = SPACE(0)
    SELECT @Str = @Str + ',' + SUBSTRING(@Str + Models.Name, 1, 10)
      FROM dbo.Models
    PRINT @Str
```

Is this something you can do on the client?  If I had the choice I would probably remove it from the data layer and put it on the client, formatting it to CSV when I needed it.

Comment: this doesn't work, here is what it returns: _,Jeep,,JeepHonda,,Jeep,,Jee,,Jeep,,Jee_

Comment: oh, you can just adjust the substring of the @Str to not include the ,